# MS Access "id" is not a valid index

Tags: ms-access

When I try to open my access database I get an error that says id is not a valid index.

I did not change the layout of the database at all. The database is live on a website and it is able to edit and add to it without a problem.

What can I do to open the database?

Comment: When I open the database I am able to see all of the tables that are within it. One of the tables is reading "MSysCompactError. I try to open one of the tables and it reads "ID is not an index in this table. That just keeps coming up when i close or hit ok.

Comment: You're using an inappropriate database engine for a website, to begin with, so nobody is really going to be able to give you anything like a permanent solution. Sounds like a corrupted index, but what is causing it is anybody's guess, as you're running your database in an environment it was not intended to be deployed in.

Comment: I did not write this website, I have just recently taken it over as the previous developer was unable to maintain the website.

So is it my understanding then that access is not meant to run a website back end? I have never used it until now for a website, SQL/MYSQL was always a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found this on Internet. It may help you
You can do following approach

At first, I tried to “Compact and Repair” the database. That didn’t work. Next, I tried creating a new database and importing the tables, forms, reports and queries from the corrupted database. When I tried the import, I just got a bunch of “ID is not an index in this table” messages and nothing more. The import would stop at this point.

What eventually worked was to open the corrupted database and manually export each object from the corrupted database to a brand new database. I was able to do this with the export tools in the ribbon bar and by selecting “Access” as my export option. I did have to create the new, blank database first; the database to export all of the data to.

Unfortunately, I could only export one object at a time. So it took a while to do;

Answer Source : "http://www.lmhproductions.com/237/microsoft-access-id-is-not-an-index-in-this-table/"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have special keys enabled? You may try skipping startup routines if there are any. You do that by holding shift key while starting. Once you get it opened you may be able to repair it.
It sounds likely there is a corruption of a table index. You should backup and be sure to keep any old backup handy as well. If you can, try compact and repair on a copy then the usual round of corruption Hail Marys.

Comment: I have a backup from a month ago, there are not a huge number of changes thank goodness, but I would like to know at least how this broke so it does not occur again. Compact and repair has not done anything to repair it ..

Comment: in a quick search I found this helpful site regarding reasons for corruption: (http://allenbrowne.com/ser-25.html)

Comment: So I fixed my database all up yesterday, had everything working pefectly. I have gone back to look at it today and everything is corrupt. I am the only person who is able to get into the database.

It is saying that id is not a valid index, and another error saying visual basic had an error..

Comment: I feel for you. There must be some kind of interruption taking place. I have not used Access for website before so I am sorry I have no ideas for you.