# 'Id' is not an index in this table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I think my database is corrupted. Every time I open the database or any object (table, forms, reports) in the database, I get an error message that says

> "'Id' is not an index in this table".

I created a new DB and tried to export the objects in the DB. I was only able to export the tables, not the forms or report.  Help please

My other attempts to fix the problem both failed:

- compact & repair
- Turned off the Name AutoCorrect check boxes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access "id" is not a valid index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883456/ms-access-id-is-not-a-valid-index)

Comment: What do you mean?